# chrome.runtime.sendMessage inside background page of extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to use a chrome messaging between components inside the background page of my extension.
But it works strange.

**This works**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log('message received', request);
});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage('test1');
```

But when I add callback to `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` it **does not work**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  console.log('message received', request);
  sendResponse(123);
});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage('test2', function(data) {
  console.log('resp:', data, chrome.runtime.lastError);
});
```

And lastError contains *Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist*

Can anybody explain this weird behavior?

**UPDATE:**
Starting from Chrome 49, neither of the snippets in the question work, because the fact that the first snippet worked was a bug (crbug.com/479425)
Thanks to [rob-w](https://stackoverflow.com/users/938089/rob-w).

Comment: Forgive me the naive question, but why would you want to send messages internally on the background page? Messages are meant as a means to communicate between the extension and external resources (content scripts, native apps, other extensions etc)

Comment: I have many modules in background page and messages are useful way to communicate between them.

Comment: Modules? So you have one background page with several Javascript files in it? If not, please explain with a little more detail

Comment: Yes, many js files (classes) in background that need to communicate with each other. Of course, I can call public methods directly as they all in one context, but using notify/subscription makes classes less linked

Comment: Starting from Chrome 49, neither of the snippets in your question work, because the fact that the first snippet worked was a bug (https://crbug.com/479425). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857606/chrome-messaging-chrome-runtime-sendmessage-not-working-on-the-newest-release-49