# May i use sendResponce/onMessage within event page? (bug?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Seems like i can send message, but can't receive response. Everything works fine when i use sendMessage from another context (popup, content script, etc).

Is it bug?

**event-page.js**

```
(function (chrome, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        console.info('onMessage: ' + message.method);

        switch (message.method) {
            case 'withResponseAsync':
                setTimeout(function () {
                    sendResponse({some: 'response'});
                }, 1000);
                return true;
                break;

            case 'withResponse':
                sendResponse({some: 'response'});
                break;
        }
    });


    var showResponse = function (response) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }

        console.info(response);
    };

    // ok. onMessage: noResponse
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: 'noResponse'});

    // fail. Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: 'withResponse'}, showResponse);

    // fail. Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: 'withResponseAsync'}, showResponse);

})(chrome);
```

Comment: You cannot send a message from a page to the same page, since that makes no sense. If you want to test message passing, use two different pages, e.g. a popup page and a content script.

Comment: But actually i can send 'simple' message (without response).

Comment: "since that makes no sense"
I want reuse existing onMessage handler from other parts of event page same as from other pages.

same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551614/chrome-runtime-sendmessage-inside-background-page-of-extension

Comment: Yes, the fact that you can pass a simple message is probably a bug. The API does not send messages to the same context normally.