# Chrome messaging: chrome.runtime.sendMessage not working on the newest release 49

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome extension that works perfectly fine on version 48 but for some reason, isn't working on 49 and am not able to find anything on their release/change log.

The part that isn't working is the message passing.

**Backgound page:**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender){
console.log(msg);
});

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({info:"this is a test"});
```

This will not output anything on version 49, but will on version 48.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try to debug. What errors are you getting in the console ? Try the complete syntax as written in docs i.e `function(msg, sender, sendResponse)` and see if that works.

Comment: @NikhilSharma I wish to tell you it worked, but it doesn't. I also wish there was some sort of error, but sadly, it doesn't return anything back. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Let me reproduce this on my machine, then I will let you know.

Comment: @NikhilSharma Thank you! Make sure you have at least version: 49.0.2623.75 m.
Messages do come in when being sent from content script, but they do not appear to be caught by the listener when dispatched from the same background page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour. Messages were not supposed to be received by the sending page. The old behaviour was a bug. This is discussed in these bug reports: [479425](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479425) [479951](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479951).

Comment: Thank you for that! But how do I trigger an event from within the background page and catch it within the background page?

Comment: @hex20dec If you are on the same page you can call a function directly, no need for message passing. Anyway, if you want you can use for instance the standard Events API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events